# Geolocation of all leads and accounts in Sales Cloud

Tags: account, map, leads, geolocation, sales-cloud

my fashion organization is planning to buy Sales Cloud.
One of the requirements of the sales men is to see in a map (Google Maps style) all leads and accounts (with type = "store") and also the accounts (with type = "competitor") related to a single "store" at the same time.

Is there something of native in Salesforce?
If not, is it possible to develop this?

What's your suggestions?

I found out there are many payed apps like MapAnything but they aren't free and we don't want to bind to third-party companies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what's referred to as a "Mashup" and would require development of a custom page to display two different objects and the two different record types (store for both Accounts and Leads, plus competitor for Accounts). This is something you'd need to pay a developer to create for you either in the Lightning UI (preferred since a new org would by default use Lightning) or in Visualforce, or some combination of the two.

At a minimum, you'd still need a Google maps integration and may still want to purchase a MapAnything license because there's a limit on how many calls you can make to Google maps without paying them for a license.